# How to put an animation on texts from a navbar after clicking on them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to put an animation (from Animista) in order to make navbar (a tag) text disapear when you click on it

So this is the navbar, I would like to put the css animation on Home Features Pricing About :

```css
.tracking-out-contract {
 -webkit-animation: tracking-out-contract 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
         animation: tracking-out-contract 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes tracking-out-contract {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      letter-spacing: -0.5em;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes tracking-out-contract {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      letter-spacing: -0.5em;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
              <ul class="container-fluid navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Do I need some Javascript here ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.tracking-out-contract {
 -webkit-animation: tracking-out-contract 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
         animation: tracking-out-contract 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes tracking-out-contract {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      letter-spacing: -0.5em;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  @keyframes tracking-out-contract {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      letter-spacing: -0.5em;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
      <ul class="container-fluid navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >Features</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >Pricing</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >About</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you just put animation on active menu items?

```
.nav-link:active,
.nav-link:focus {
    -webkit-animation: tracking-out-contract 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
            animation: tracking-out-contract 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}
```

Comment: doesn't look to change :/ still basic bootstrap hover

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use javascript's `onclick` event to add css class.
`$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')`

For example:

```
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
      <ul class="container-fluid navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >Features</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >Pricing</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            onclick="$(this).addClass('tracking-out-contract')"
            >About</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```